# how to use a single boolean variable in angular and use in different fields dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form with 10 text aria and 10 cke editor .on load i will show them only text area .

there is a toggle button in top of every text editor and on calling this toggle function the editor should change to cke editor

> I was able to do this for  one of the editor

-

> I don't want to declare 10 boolean variables for this .. is there a
>   way that i can handle this.???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Array

```
toggle=[];

<div  *ngFor="let d of data;let i=index" (click)="toggle[i]=!toggle[i]" >
{{d}}
<p *ngIf="toggle[i]" >{{'data'}}</p>
</div>
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bgkc6h